# Is there a name for generalized manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

A topological manifold is a topological space which locally resembles real $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. Here I consider removing `Euclidean' from manifold:

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space, and $M$ is a topological space which locally resembles $X$, i.e. for each $p\in M$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$, an open set $V$ in $X$, and a homeomorphism $\varphi: U\rightarrow V$. Is there a name for $M$?

And is there a book about orbifolds for beginners? I only know some basic concepts of differential manifolds.

Comment: nLab has a notion of [G-manifolds](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/manifold#definition_via_pseudogroups) that fits your setting.

Comment: Search for the lecture notes for "Geometry and the Imagination". Bill Thurston uses quotient orbifolds to give an elegant proof of the classification of plane symmetries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no name for such spaces. One just call them locally homeomorphic to the space $M$. Usually one needs to relate with the local homeomorphism the topological space and a euclidean space, since the euclidean structure coupled with the local homeomorphisms allows us to bring all differential calculus on the manifold.

Let me build on Christoph’s suggestion instead (thank you, I was not aware of them either): if the space $X$ is endowed with at least a structure of pseudogroup, then one may want to call the whole manifold a [$G$-manifold](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/manifold#definition_via_pseudogroups).

For a fast introduction to orbifolds, I would give a first look [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-904-seminar-in-topology-spring-2011/final-paper/MIT18_904S11_finlOrbifolds.pdf).

Comment: Note that you can always equip $X$ with the trivial pseudogroup of the open sets in $X$ with all their homeomorphisms.